# Confusing combinatorial book problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm trying to solve this problem:

In a shelf there are two books of five different subjects. Compute the probability of none of the books keep together of the same subject.

I'm having trouble to solve this problem. I begin computing the probability of the complement, i.e., the probability of at least one couple of same subject keeps together. Let $A$ be the set of previous event. So, $A=\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{5}A_{i},$ where $A_{i}$ denotes the event of couple $i$ is the same subject. So, using inclusion-exclusion formula we can calculate that probability. But, when I tried to compute each probaility I have hard problems: for example, to calculate $P(A_{1})$ I've been thinking that $P(A_{1})=\frac{8!·5·2}{10!},$ but in this way I'm not consider the possibility of the remain $8$ books can be keep together.

What about $P(A_{i}\cap A_{j})$ and $P(A_{i}\cap\ A_{j}\cap A_{k})?$

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: "In a shelf there are two books of five different subjects. Compute the probability of none of the books keep together of the same subject." Are there 2 or 10 books? What do you mean by "books keep together"? Etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

Assume 2 books of which subjects are independent and uniformly random. Let$(i,j)$ denote first book is from subject i and second book is from j. Then there are 25 possible such pairs and 5 of them are in the complement.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\blank{\bbox[lemonchiffon, 1ex, border:1pt blue dashed]{\raise{1ex}\qquad}}$

We have five pairs of items, so there are $\blank$ equally probable ways to arrange them.

Let us count the ways that *at least* one pair are together using PIE (Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion).

$$\blank-\blank+\blank-\blank+\blank$$

This is the complement of our favoured event, so the probability we seek is:

$$\dfrac{\blank-\blank+\blank-\blank+\blank-\blank}{\blank} ~=~ \dfrac{47}{135}$$